# Find Particular Node's Child Element From XML Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

i have a xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<childrens>
<child id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
  <child id="2" value="Apparel" parent_id="1">
  <child id="4" value="Shirts" parent_id="2"/>
<child id="5" value="Pants" parent_id="2"/>
</child>
<child id="3" value="Accessories" parent_id="1">
  <child id="6" value="Handbags" parent_id="3"/>
  <child id="7" value="Jewelry" parent_id="3"/>
</child>
 .
 .
 .
<child id='1110'>
   <child id='1111' value="test" parent_is="1110">
       <child id="1005" value="test1" parent_is="1111"/>
       <child id="1006" value="test12" parent_is="1111"/>
       <child id="1007" value="test123" parent_is="1111"/>
    <child>
</child>
<child >
</childrens>
```

i am using jquery to find a particular nodes children

i have written this code to find the child of the node where `id=1111` and `value=test`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('child[value="test"]').each(function(){
                var i = $(this).attr('value');
                alert(i);

            });
        }
    });
});
```

it gives me only one name which is it self

while i need in output three name which is its child element

which is `test1`, `tets12`, `test123`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

```
$(xml).find('child[value="test"]').children().each(function(){
    ...
});
```