# How to get the parent tag in a list view and how to get their children tags when click on particular parent

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I'm very new to jquery. Can any one help me to get the parent in the list view and when we click on particular parent we have to get the corresponding children.

My XMl File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <page count="56" name="ebook">
    <sections>
    <section count="7" name="Seduce Your Partner" order="1">
      <content file="93828.txt" order="1">Balmy with rich perfumes</content>
      <content file="93829.txt" order="2">Wear a fine dress</content>
      <content file="93830.txt" order="3">Welcome to Love Abode</content>
      <content file="93831.txt" order="4">Rekindle your love</content>
      <content file="93832.txt" order="5">Flower a love messanger</content>
      <content file="93833.txt" order="6">Perfumes and Aromas</content>
      <content file="93834.txt" order="7">Gain a women&amp;apos;s heart</content>
    </section>
    <section count="6" name="The Touch of Love" order="2">
      <content file="93835.txt" order="8">A Love Message</content>
      <content file="93836.txt" order="9">An awakening kiss</content>
      <content file="93837.txt" order="10">Heading South with Confidence</content>
      <content file="93838.txt" order="11">Caressing</content>
      <content file="93839.txt" order="12">Stroking</content>
      <content file="93840.txt" order="13">Blows &amp;amp; Cries</content>
    </section>
    <section count="8" name="Beyond Touch" order="3">
      <content file="93841.txt" order="14">Watch, Listen &amp;amp; Experiment</content>
      <content file="93842.txt" order="15">Blindfolded</content>
      <content file="93843.txt" order="16">Embrace of Jaghana</content>
      <content file="93844.txt" order="17">Piercing Embrace</content>
      <content file="93845.txt" order="18">Twining of a Creeper</content>
      <content file="93846.txt" order="19">Line of Jewels</content>
      <content file="93847.txt" order="20">Token of Remembrance</content>
      <content file="93848.txt" order="21">Oils and Lotions</content>
    </section>
  </sections>
</page>
```

My Html File:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>XML File</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>

    <script src="script1.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Home Page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Mobile Viewer</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="section_list" data-role="listview">
            <!-- <ul id="content_list" data-role="listview">
            </ul> -->
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Chapter Page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="chapter">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
            <h1></h1>
            <a href="" data-role="button" class="next" data-icon="forward" data-iconpos="notext">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="content_list" data-role="listview">
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want output Like:

All parents are in list view using attribute name like:

Seduce your Partner
The Touch of Love
.
.
.

so when i click on "Seduce Your Partner" i want to get the children in list view under this tag .

Thanks in Advance..

Thank u its working fine but can u plz check this one with My html page:

```
$(document).ready(function()

{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "449.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function parseXml(xml)
    {

    $(xml).find('section[name]').each(function() {

             var section = $(this).attr("name");

        $("#section_list").append('<li><a href='+ "#chapter" + ' id="">' + section + '  </a> </li>');

        $("#section_list").listview('refresh');

    });

    $(xml).children().each(function() {

    var content = $(this).text();   

    $("#content_list").append('<li><a href='+ "#" + 'id="" ">' + content + ' </a> </li> ');

    $("#content_list").listview('refresh');

    });
}
 });
});
```

i'm getting the listview of parents with name attribute but when i'm clicking on anyone of the parent getting the same thing for every link and also its displaying the content in single list.

can you solve this problem for getting the solution as each parent can get only their children content in listview.

Comment: Hey buddy, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583461/find-particular-nodes-child-element-from-xml-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i tried this one i didn't get the solution.can you please give the example code for this xml example.

Comment: :check the code snippet

Comment: How are you populating the listview with parents currently?

Comment: sorry for late reply skukx.. i'm getting the parent tags with attribute name and i update my code can u check this one and help me to get the child tags of particular parent.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @user2139922: ` $(xml).find('section[name]').each(function() {` Where is the condition here bro, you were suppose to add the cond as name=" section_name". i think it should have been as `$(xml).children().each(function() {` , so that when you click on **sections** tags, it would consider **section** tags,similarly, ** Contents** tags when **section** tags are clicked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

       $('#button').on('click',function() {
            // getting all child elements based on the parent name
                var parNode="Seduce Your Partner";
                var data='<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>........... ';
                var list='';
                //$.get('sample.xml', null, function (data, textStatus) {
                        list='<ul>';
                        $(data).find('sections section[name="Seduce Your Partner"]').children().each(function () {
                            list+='<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>';
                        });
                         list+='<ul>';
            //}, 'xml');
                $('#targetDiv').text(list);

      } );

});
```

This code is for getting all the child elements . i suppose you would know how to get the parent node`s name, since thats the input for the above code.

Similarly you can get the parent node with reference from child node, using .`closest()` .

**EDIT :the above code has been updated and its working copy is** [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mJJET/)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for giving reply buddy but i'm not getting anything. I'm getting only header and footer only..

Comment: Above code will generate the list of child elements in list variables, i suppose you need to know the target element within which u have to display the final **list** (variable). `$('#targetEle').text(list);`

Comment: yes i set the target variable but still getting the same i dont known the mistake where i'm doing but when i tried in this way i'm getting something can u plz check this code once

Comment: @user2139922: pls dont include code in comments section its difficult to understand, better edit your question and add it, i`ll check the same at my side as well simultaneously

Comment: ohh sorry..from next time i will do this actually i'm new to this

Comment: @user2139922:here is the updated and working copy of my code http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/mJJET/

Comment: @user2139922: The code is working as per your requirement, im not sure why your finding it so difficult to incorporate in your code. anyway, just add the complete code on jsfiddle, i`ll check it once :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/Veqs6/10/ acually i'm very new to jquery that's why..can help me to complete this work.Thanks in advance

Comment: oh...sorry in that link i didn't include my xml data in code can try that link using above xml file..Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2139922: hope this is what you wanted,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Veqs6/13/

Comment: @user2139922: I have used static data,you can use the data from xml itself,using ajax call, it will work smoothly

Comment: Thank u..buddy but when i'm clicking on the link1(seduce your partner) it will getting all the child("content") tags in xml file. what i want is when i click on link1(seduce your partner) it will display only their seven child("content") tags of that section.like this for every section tag display only their child tags...Thanks in Advance

Comment: buddy i'm getting the all childs of all parents only..can u help me to get the child of that parent only..Thanks in Advance.